# Contract Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: transactions

My ICO crowdsale contract had

> Contract Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfe4349d2e054fb7d48a7383d7145afe8852974f702f8a99c08daadc4d706c3ba

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1b2f1ddb9696bb6869999636121277c271f6f23c#code

Does anyone know what issue and help ?

Comment: Can you share the Solidity code and the code that calls the smart contract?

Comment: Most likely, the require condition in contract function failed. If you put custom error message in require condition, you will see that in remix that which condition failed.

Comment: Here is the Solidity code https://etherscan.io/address/0x1b2f1ddb9696bb6869999636121277c271f6f23c#code

Answer (score 0):

From the [parity's transaction trace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xfe4349d2e054fb7d48a7383d7145afe8852974f702f8a99c08daadc4d706c3ba&type=parity)

```
Action [6]  
    CallType:   call
    From:    0x1b2f1ddb9696bb6869999636121277c271f6f23c
    Gas:    3849695 Gwei
    To:  0xfc72bf8cba2a82fd887f35ce36fbec5d8ed97465
    Value:  0 Ether
    BlockHash:  0xbf2163124c4db9200787f305e03025ad4bf174d3107b7f116c43c28f7fc4e6b9
    BlockNumber:    7047218
    Error:  Reverted
    Subtraces:  0
    TraceAddress:   [ 4 ]
    TransactionHash:    0xfe4349d2e054fb7d48a7383d7145afe8852974f702f8a99c08daadc4d706c3ba
    TransactionPosition:    167
    Type:   call
```

It reverts when calling the [BtcexToken](https://etherscan.io/address/0xfc72bf8cba2a82fd887f35ce36fbec5d8ed97465#code)

Checking the balance of [BtcexCrowdsale](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1b2f1ddb9696bb6869999636121277c271f6f23c#code) the problems is obvious, it has zero tokens.

The failure is caused in `_deliverTokens` function

```
  function _deliverTokens(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _tokenAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    token.safeTransfer(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
  }
```

The crowdsale tries to transfer tokens to the beneficiary but it doesn't have enough tokens.

Perhaps the tokens wasn't correctly initialized it seemd `transferOwnershipAndTotalBalance()` should be called and it wasn't (also that function is missing a `Transfer()` event so I can't be sure).